# Pe 32 Add Export function Segment by Extending with dll or Patching pe

Tags: windows, c++, pe, assembly

I need to add new function inside pe32 module.dll Export Table , in dynamic way if possible ( via extending with dll ) or by patching pe32 module.dll

What can u suggest to solve this ?

Comment: what is your final goal with this?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky i want to handle function that is being called from .exe and process it's object data. I did some workaround renaming function that is missing in .dll to existing but not used function is same .dll , and hooking it via trampoline . But i'm worried it might create some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know any tool to solve your problem easily, I will tell you how it can be done "by hand".

First of all, you have to be familiar with PE format. If you are not, you may check [aldeid](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PE-Portable-executable) and [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) to understand the steps I will describe. Adding an export to `dll` is just extending `Export Directory` and possibly changing some other fields. So, what you have to do is to:

1. Open your `dll` in PE parser. It can be [PE Explorer](http://www.pe-explorer.com/), [CFF Explorer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) or in disassembler such as IDA (tick manual load, and then load all possible sections).
2. Open your favourite hex editor in order to patch `dll`. Some changes may be done in above mentioned PE parsers, but not all.
3. Increase `ExportDirectory.NumberOfFunctions` by `1`, since you are adding new function.
4. Do the same thing with `ExportDirectory.NumberOfNames`.
5. Now, you have to add new entry to `Export Address Table`, which is located at `ExportDirectory.AddressOfFunctions`. Just use hex editor to insert `4` new NULL bytes - you will set their value when you insert your function's code.
6. After previous step, `ExportDirectory.AddressOfNames` has probably changed (by `4` bytes). You have to adjust it as well.
7. Now, insert new entry to `ExportDirectory.AddressOfNames` - insert another `4` bytes using hex editor. Later on, you will change it to the name of your function.
8. As in step 6. and 7., adjust `ExportDirectory.AddressOfNameOrdinals` and add `2` bytes using hex editor (highest ordinal `+ 1`, write it in little endian).
9. Since you have inserted several new bytes, you have to change `ExportDirectory.Name` as well, to point to the `dll` name.
10. Now, insert your function's name at the end of the table of function names (last entry in `ExportDirectory.AddressOfNames`).
11. Set the entry you have created in 7. so it points to your function name.
12. Insert your function's code at the end of `.text` section (if it is small enough, you won't have to resize it).
13. Set the entry you have created in 5.
14. Change `Export Directory Size` to match your new size.
15. Use the same value for changing `SectionHeader.VirtualSize` for `.edata` section.
16. Increase `FileHeader.NumberOfSymbols` by `1`.
17. Either increase `SectionTable.SizeOfRawData` for `ExportDirectory` by number of bytes you have inserted using hex editor, or delete as this number of NULL bytes at the end of `ExportDirectory` (if present).
18. Zero out or compute new `OptionalHeader.CheckSum`.

As you see, it's a tedious process to do this manually and even if you find doing it too difficult, I hope that at least you see what has to be done "at low level" to add new export to a `dll`.